# Python - Timestamp Conversion

Tags: python-2.7, timestamp, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

I have converted some sensor data into `CSV` format. The data contains a `timestamp` attribute that is divided into two parts as follows:

```
measurement_timestamp_begin: 
  seconds: 3733032665
  fractions: 3056174174
```

I need to convert this into standard UNIX timestamp format. I saw several posts for doing the conversion but each method receives a single argument. I don't understand the **fraction** part.  Does it mean **seconds.fraction**? e.g. **3733032665.3056174174**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code converts above mentioned timestamp format to standard UNIX timestamp format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime, time

unix_epoch = datetime.date(*time.gmtime(0)[0:3])

ntp_epoch = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)

ntp_delta = (unix_epoch - ntp_epoch).days * 24 * 3600

def ntp_to_unix_time(date):
    return (date - ntp_delta)

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ntp_to_unix_time(3733032665.3056174174))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```